# error in running java program in windows cmd

Tags: java

I am facing an error when run the below java program on windows command prompt.
Basically, I am a C/C++ programmer , but i need to run a java file as a part of some testing..

Following is the content of my TestClass.java, not copied full code as it looks like some kind of path or package issue.

```
package parse_signature;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String path_of_file= "input/content.txt";
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path_of_file));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    ....
    }
}
```

I am in the directory: `C:/Users/Desktop/JavaPRGs/Test/`, when i used the command `javac TestClass.java`,

`TestClass.class` got created and when i run `java TestClass`

I get following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class TestClass
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: parse_signature/TestClass (wrong name: TestClass)
```

I tried going back to previous directory `C:/Users/Desktop/JavaPRGs` and ran `java Test.TestClass`
got the same error (only this difference wrong name: Test/TestClass)

Also tried follwing, but the result is same.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\java -cp . Test.TestClass
```

Comment: can you put your source code online so i can replicate it? here's a tutorial: https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/first-java-program/

Comment: your class is in a package, are you keeping that in mind? also: why is your main method throwing an Exception? you want your application to crash?

Comment: @doppelgunner no, everything that's needed to reproduce the problem should be in the question.

Comment: Java expects the package to be part of the path to the class file.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html

Comment: @dave_thompson, the link helped me , looks like the directory name and class name should be same , its looks ridiculous as a C/C++ programmer, but i am not qualified enough to comment anyway, thanks again

Comment: No, the directory name(s) should be the _package_ name or its components. The _file_ name should be the class name, plus the suffix `.java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the package and try to compile and run it again using 
`javac TestClass.java` and `java TestClass`

Comment: sorry for late reply, the sample program (Hello World) i have already tried that is working fine, because it does not include any packages, in your second comment you mentioned to remove the package , i have removed , now this time the error is removed, but i dont get any output, i have updated the code with few more lines, plz guide me

Comment: @sravs, the code snippet you shared does not actually have any output instructions so of course it won't output anything.

Comment: @Taschi, actually that part i have not pasted , i was referring to my code, anyway the solution for the problem is solved by both doppelgunner and dave